# What happens if the expression in a match arm returns false?

Tags: rust

This would be a nice fizzbuzz in Rust I think:

```
match (i % 3, i % 5) {
    (0, 0) => println!("FizzBuzz"),
    (0, _) => println!("Fizz"),
    (_, 0) => println!("Buzz"),
    _ => println!("{}", i),
}
```

It could also be stated this way:

```
match i {
    i if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 => println!("FizzBuzz"),
    i if i % 3 == 0 => println!("Fizz"),
    i if i % 5 == 0 => println!("Buzz"),
    _ => println!("{}", i),
}
```

Now that confused me.

```
i if i % 3 == 0
```

is an expression, right? So, this evaluates to `i` when the condition is true. But what happens if it is false?

Comment: That first one is a pretty neat FizzBuzz, I never thought of that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Now that confused me.
>
> ```
> i if i % 3 == 0
> ```
>
> is an expression, right?

No, it is not. It is a pattern (`i`) with a [guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#guards) (`i % 3 == 0`). Maybe you got confused because you used the same bind name. Consider this modified example:

```
match i {
    x if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0 => println!("FizzBuzz"),
    x if x % 3 => println!("Fizz"),
    x if x % 5 => println!("Buzz"),
    _ => println!("{}", x),
}
```

You can read the match expression like this

- If `i` matches the pattern `x` (it always match and `i` value is moved (copied) to `x`) and `x % 3 == 0` and `x % 5 == 0` then `println!("FizzBuzz")`; else
- if `i` matches the pattern `x` and `x % 3 == 0` then `println!("Fizz")`; else
- if `i` matches the pattern `x` and `x % 5 == 0` then `println!("Buzz")`; else
- `println!("{}", x)`

Answer (score 2):

If it is false, the match arm is simply not called. These are called guards in the match statement. You can read about them in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#guards).

They are *similar* to an `if-else` but not in the case that there is an `else` block. They just add more filtering to the match blocks.

Answer (score 2):

> `i if i % 3` is an expression, right?

No, it's not. `i if i % 3 == 0` is a pattern, which consists of the simple pattern `i` and the pattern guard `if i % 3 == 0`. A pattern guard is the keyword `if` followed by a boolean expression. It can come after any simple pattern (where by "simple pattern" I mean any pattern that doesn't already have a pattern guard).

If a pattern with an attached pattern guard matches, the pattern guard will be evaluated. If it evaluates to true, the associated branch will be executed. Otherwise the next pattern will be called as if the pattern had not matched.